# implement a delete function into a javascript pop up button

Tags: javascript, django, database, variables

Can anyone tell me how i can implement a delete function into a javascript pop up button?

1. I have created a for loop which shows elements in my database.
2. In this for loop I have created a "delete" button in html that activates a javascript pop-up.
3. The javascript pop-up asks the user to confirm "if he wants to delete the item or not?"
4. If the user wants to confirm deleting the specific item (item.id) he can click on the second "delete" button that is shown in the javascript pop-up.
5. This second "delete" button should delete the item by generating a dynamic link (e.g.  ... /delete/3)

I have successfully linked the javascript variable into the dynamic link but the content of the jinja variable isn't passed to the javascript variable.

```
** For loop :**

{% for item in all %}
<button class="button"onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Delete</button><br>
{{ item.Bedrijfsnaam }}<br>
{{ item.Voornaam }}<br>
{{item.id}}
<meta name="item-id" content="{{ item.id }}"></meta>
{% endfor %}

**Javascript :**

var idlink = "delete/" + $('#item-id').data();

**HTML button with dynamic link :**

<button type="button" onclick="parent.location=idlink" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>
```

** However the link that is created remains void: **

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/[object%20Object]](http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/%5Bobject%20Object%5D)

How can I solve this problem?

The point is that I want to delete an item out of my database by clicking a button in my HTML code that generates a dynamic link. However I want to use javascript to show a popup to confirm the delete action before deleting the item.

Comment: can you show whats in urls.py and views.py

Comment: urls.py: path('delete/<member_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
views.py : item = members.objects.get(pk=member_id)

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
path('delete/<int:pk>', views.delete, name='delete')
```

views.py

```
def delete(request, member_id)
    item = members.object.get(pk=member_id)
    item.delete()
```

button inside the loop

```
<button class="button" onclick="setPkFunc('{{item.pk}}')">Delete</button>
```

your dynamic button

```
<button id="id01" onclick="deleteFunc()" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>
```

javascript

```
<script>
  var link = "";
  function setPkFunc(pk) {
    link = "delete/" + pk;
    document.getElementById("id01").style.display="block";
  }
  function deleteFunc() {
    parent.location = link;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the delete function in my views.py?
For the moment I run a function in my views.py named "def delete(request, member_id):" which holds the "item = members.object.get(pk=member_id)" variable and executes "item.delete()".

Comment: No, it didn't work. After all I just added my dynamic button inside the loop and adjusted my view.py function which seemed to contain a name error. After this adaption the function just seemed to work fine. Although, I didn't manage to connect the javascript and html jinja variables, it worked without doing so after all.